# Migrating node.js npm project from Windows to Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, migration

I am migrating a Node project that I developed locally on Windows to a remote Linux VM.

I've copied all the source .js files and package .json files to the Linux VM **(not the node-modules directory**), and when I run `npm install`, I am faced with many `node-gyp ERR` errors related to things like python, pkg-config, and other dependencies that I did not have to deal with when I created the project in Windows. I may have simply installed "windows-build-tools" locally on Windows.

Is there an equivalent for Linux? What is the correct strategy when migrating a Node project from one OS to another?